# Easy way to control homepage content with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, store

So I've done creating the cms for e-commerce that will handle all the operations for products, categories ...etc, now I want to control the content of the homepage like setting featured products, offers, and new collections.

**What's the best idea to make an easy control page to edit this content?**

I've tried to use **Presets** like this:

[image]

but of course, there should be another idea

Comment: “Best” is subjective. For you it may be one thing, for someone else - another. While it’s not possible to mark question as opinion-based, it will be brought to moderator’ attention.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov by "Best" I mean a way that works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a category like table, but only to control the e-commerce home.

Another option could be to use polymorphic tables. A polymorphic relationship allows the target model to belong to more than one type of model using a single association.

Then you could make a table like the one you put in your question, but with associated products, banners or categories, this way you wouldn't be touching resources you shouldn't.

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: Great! the polymorphic relationship clearly solves the preset type issue, thanks but what about the idea in general? is it good to use something called **Presets** to control the e-commerce home, or is there a better idea?

Comment: If you are referring to what is the best name to give the model and the table depends on your taste, but I would call it Sections or HomeSections

Comment: Yeah this naming really help, is there a laravel package for controlling homepage contents?

Comment: I don't know any.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have used on a live site

**For all the contents that rarely changes**

1. created table `site_contents` with cols id,page,key,value(text)

[image]

2. The value is jsonable, on your model mention it to autocast as array or object so that you dont have to json_decode all the time

   $casts = ['value' => 'array']
3. Now on controller you query each page as `SiteContent::where('key', $page)->get(['id', 'key', 'value'])`
4. Upon saving if there can be multiple keys (like banners), use `create()` method. And if key has to be unique (like mission) use `updateOrCreate()` method

**For the contents that frequently changes**

Frequent changes occurs on Popular Products, Featured Products or ...
I suggest to add is_popular, is_featured, is_latest flags to the products table and manually query them wherever required

If you want to dump it to table as you have shown in your question writing the dumping codes to your Product model as shown below

**Product Model**

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function ($product) {
        if ($product->is_featured) {
            // write your code to dump it to site_contents table
            // or create an event ProductCreated and fire that here
        }
    });

    static::updated(function ($product) {
        if ($product->isDirty('is_featured ')) {
            // someone changed the is_featured flag
            if($product->is_featured) {
              // dump to site_contents table
            } else {
              // remove from site_contents table
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Using booleans like "is_featured" is so good to define attributes, although I'm using many platforms to show the data so I can't simply store it as json in the database :(

Comment: If you dont want to use booleans, you may create a seprate table like featured_products. But if you dont want anything to be stored on database, then add a multiselect will all products. As per the selection made you will directly updating the site_contents table.

Comment: Regarding, not using json value you may add additional nullable columns as per json keys

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to develope the pages on blade without having to get content from database. trust me it worth it. cause you can add many features to your views.

And if it is an ecommerce website, well it's gonna be more difficult to manage seo and tracking events.

What should be dynamic instead is your products, categories to fetch them and add them to your views.

Comment: Products, categories and other data are already dynamic, but I need to manage the way to show them as featured on homepage.

Comment: Ah okay, so for my own project what i do is i set a widget like Wordpress where i add on my own blade file. this is the package i use: https://github.com/arrilot/laravel-widgets

So for exemple if i want to show featured products i jus add this to home page: 
{{ Widget::run('featuredProducts') }}